# Behavour of nested quotes in Scheme and Racket

Tags: scheme, racket, quote, repl-printed-representation

While writing a function in Racket I accidently put two single quotes in front of a symbol instead of one.  i.e. I accidently wrote ''a  and discovered some behaviour of nested quotes that seems strange.  I'm using DrRacket and tested this with both the Racket lang and the R5RS lang.

```
(write (pair? (quote (quote a))))
```

prints: #t .

```
(write (car (quote (quote a))))
```

prints: quote

But

```
(write (quote (quote a)))
```

and

```
(write '(quote a)))
```

Both print: 'a

Can someone tell me why in Scheme (and Racket) the function pair? interprets (quote (quote a))) as a pair of two elements quote and a , but the function write prints out 'a instead of (quote a) .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Putting a quote mark (`'`) around a term and wrapping a `quote` form around it are identical. That is, they `read` to the same term.

So all of the following expressions are identical in Scheme:

```
''a
'(quote a)
(quote 'a)
(quote (quote a))
```

The `quote` form means "interpret what comes next as a datum---even if it contains another `quote`". The sub-term is parenthesized, so it's a list; the inner `quote` is just a symbol.

In some cases, the printer uses reader-abbreviations like the quote mark (`'`) in its output. I'm a little surprised that you got `write` to do it, though; for me, it always writes as `(quote a)`.

Comment: I used DrRacket with both #lang r5rs and #lang racket and executed (write '(quote a)) and (write ''a) in both the definitions window and the interactions window and in all cases they printed 'a .

Comment: @HarrySpier, aha, probably has to do with DrRacket's pretty printing. If you write it to another port, like a string port (see `open-output-string`, etc), it produces `(quote a)`.

Comment: Thanks Ryan.  Just after I asked the question I found in the Racket Guide 2.4.1 Quoting pairs and symbols with quote.  The ' abbreviation works in output as well as input. "The REPL’s printer recognizes the symbol 'quote as the first element of a two-element list when printing output, in which case it uses ’ to print the output."

Comment: By chance in the Racket guide I found a special case where ''a doesn't mean '(quota a) .  If you look at: Racket Guide 15.1.3 Namespaces and Modules it has the code snippet for the DrRacket interactive window of:
The module->namespace function takes a quoted module path and produces a namespace for evaluating expressions and definitions as if they appeared in the module body:
> (module m racket/base
    (define x 11))
> (require 'm)
> (define ns (module->namespace ''m))
> (eval 'x ns)
The inner ' indicates its a interactively declared module path and the second ' makes it a quoted form.